# Leaflet : Function to initialize map container

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, leaflet, openstreetmap

Have the latitude and longitude of various places in a html table, on clicking the row,a function sends the latitude and longitude values to a javascript function which loads the openstreetmap map and marker in a bootstrap modal.
This works the first time the function is called, the marker is shown but on closing the modal and the function is called again I get the error

**Uncaught Error: Map container is already initialized.**

```
function sendlatlng(id) {
       var geom=document.getElementById('cor'+id).value;
       var geom1=document.getElementById('cod'+id).value;
      var map = L.map(('map'),{scrollWheelZoom:true}).setView([geom,geom1], 12);
       L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
         {
            maxZoom: 18
         }).addTo(map);
       L.marker([geom,geom1]).addTo(map);

            }
```

Is there a way that the map div

```
<div id="map" class="map" style="height: 300px;"></div>
```

Is re initialized every time the modal is opened or the function is called.

Answer (score 1):

The error coming from leaflet because we are trying to create a map container each time `sendlatlng` is executed.  That's ok, because instead of trying to create the map and marker in the `sendlatlng` function, we can create those once, and then use the function to update the coordinates of the existing objects. Here is an example:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>A Leaflet map!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <style>
        #map {
            width: 450px;
            height: 250px
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>
        //just for the demo
        var defaultCoords = [-41.291, -185.229];

        //set up our map
        var map = L.map('map').setView(defaultCoords, 12);
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            {
                maxZoom: 18
            }).addTo(map);

        //this is how we are going to demo our sendlatlng function
        map.on('click', onMapClick);


        //use this variable to track our marker here outside of the sendlatlng function
        var myMarker = L.marker(defaultCoords).addTo(map);

        //in our example, we are going to listend for clicks on the map to trigger
        //changes to the coords with our sendlatlng function
        function onMapClick(e) {
            sendlatlng(e.latlng)
        }


        //update the map and marker positions based on the coords passed to the function
        //we will just update our existing map and myMarker variables instead of create new ones
        function sendlatlng(coords) {
            map.setView(coords, 12);
            myMarker.setLatLng(coords);

        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

In the demo, we are triggering the sendlatlng function with a mouse click on the map. This will recenter the map and move `myMarker` to the new center.

If, for example, you wanted to create a new marker in the click location, we could do that the same way you originally had your function: by adding a new marker:  `L.marker(coords).addTo(map);`

Answer (score 0):

If you create a map and try to map it again, you'll get this error. Try the following sample codes

```
//Use this before creating the map

if (map != undefined) {
   map.remove();
}

//Use this after adding tile layer

setTimeout(function () { map.invalidateSize() }, 1200);
```